# Confusion regarding mass-spring system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, free-body-diagram

[image]

The force equation for above system is

$$
\Sigma F=ma
$$

which is
$$
m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-kx
$$

This should be always true; but confusion came as I think more on this.

When I set $a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=g$

$$
mg=-kx
$$

does this make sense? since $m>0$, $g>0$, $k>0$ then x should be $<0$ to be true.

What is the correct way to interpret this?

Comment: What is the sign of x and a?

Comment: I set x and a is positive for downward

Comment: Is this supposed to be an oscillator? Hanging from a rope, sum of F = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your system is in a gravitational field directed in the $x$ direction, which you did not specify, you have two forces acting on your body: the elastic force of the spring and the gravitational force. It is the sum of these two that you need to equate to $ma$. So the equation of motion you want to solve is

$$m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=-kx + mg$$

The gravitational force is just one of several forces that can act on a body, while the equation you wrote means that the sum of all the forces acting on a body equals the gravitational force. This is false.

Comment: Ah...... Now I get it.

Comment: I'm happy about that! Note also how the two terms on the rhs have opposite sign, meaning that the spring is pulling upwards and the gravitational field downwards.

Answer (score 0):

in your case the force stored in the spring is **-kx (hooke's law)** negative sign indicate that force is acting in different direction as of motion.now congider gravitational force,the weight of body is acting downwards and have magnitude **mg**(positive because it is in direction of motion).To sum up, now you have all forces acting on body and thus:
      **ma=-kx + mg**